# function is undefined or private while should be accessible

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to reach a method from my Accounts domain. I'm able to use any method from the `Accounts` domain in `iex` except for the `mark_as_admin/1` (the last one).

here is the domain

```
defmodule Storex.Accounts do
  import Ecto.Query, warn: false
  alias Storex.Repo
  alias Storex.Accounts.User

  def create_user(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %User{}
    |> User.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end

  def get_user!(id) do
    Repo.get!(User, id)
  end

  def new_user() do
    User.changeset(%User{}, %{})
  end

  def authenticate_user(email, password) do
    Repo.get_by(User, email: email)
    |> User.check_password(password)
  end

  def mark_as_admin(user) do
    user
    |> User.admin_changeset(%{is_admin: true})
    |> Repo.update()
  end
end
```

Here's what I type in `iex`:

```
iex(1)> alias Storex.Accounts
iex(2)> user = Accounts.get_user!(7)
[debug] QUERY OK source="accounts_users" db=2.2ms
SELECT a0."id", a0."email", a0."full_name", a0."password_hash", 
a0."is_admin", a0."inserted_at", a0."updated_at" FROM "accounts_users" 
AS a0 WHERE (a0."id" = $1) [7]

%Storex.Accounts.User{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, 
"accounts_users">,

email: "test@user.tld", full_name: "Test User", id: 7,

inserted_at: ~N[2018-01-14 11:52:14.472928], is_admin: false, password: nil,

password_hash: 
"$2b$12$I7Kq8SgkWN77W3jx2QwaNe.so6z75xtYOIzl5Ws5kqlaTniLXMyIe",

updated_at: ~N[2018-01-14 11:52:14.472935]}

iex(3)> Accounts.mark_as_admin(user)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Storex.Accounts.mark_as_admin/1 is             
undefined or private
(storex) Storex.Accounts.mark_as_admin(%Storex.Accounts.User{__meta__:     
#Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "accounts_users">, email: 
"test@user.t~ld",   full_name: "Test User", id: 7, inserted_at: 
~N[2018-01-14 11:52:14.472928], is_admin: false, password: nil, 
password_hash: 
"$2b$12$I7Kq8SgkWN77W3jx2QwaNe.so6z75xtYOIzl5Ws5kqlaTniLXMyIe", 
updated_at: ~N[2018-01-14 11:52:14.472935]})
```

Why can't I call this method ?

EDIT:
After having restarted `iex` the methods in the domain can't be called anymore:

```
iex(1)> alias Storex.Accounts  
Storex.Accounts  
iex(2)> Accounts.get_user!(7)  
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Storex.Accounts.get_user!/1 is   
undefined or private
```

Comment: Are you sure you've restarted `iex` after making that change?

Comment: I indeed did not restart the `iex`. But after restarting it, the situation is even worse. All the methods from the `Accounts` domain are  now `undefined or private`

Comment: How about `mix clean` then `mix build`?

Comment: Can you let us know a bit more about your workflow? How did you start IEx? Where is the file Storex.Accounts?

Comment: Are you starting IEx with `iex -S mix` from the project's root directory?

Comment: I'm starting iex by typing `iex -S mix phx.server`.
I just retried it and it works.

Comment: The module is located in `lib/storex/accounts/accounts.ex` and I'm pretty sure I was in the root directory.  
It's a bit odd. Do you have any idea why when I did the same thing yeasterday it wasn't working ?   Doesn't the code get recompiled each time you start the server ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should start IEx from your project's root directory with something like

`iex -S mix`.

If you edit your code and save it, you should either restart IEx the same way, call [`recompile()`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#recompile/0), or [reload any single modules](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#r/1) you've changed that you want to use, like:

```elixir
iex> recompile() # recompiles and reloads everything except mix.exs and configs

iex> r Storex.Accounts # recompiles and reloads a single module
```