# function A.B.c/1 is undefined or private when running `mix tests` but not in console

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Follow-up question to this one
[function is undefined or private while should be accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249496/function-is-undefined-or-private-while-should-be-accessible)

I'm approximatively experiencing the same issue. A function is considered undefined or private.

The solution in the link above works! In `$ iex -S mix phx.server` I run `recompile()` and the function is no longer undefined or private.

My issue is that it is still undefined or private in my tests suite.
When I run `mix tests`, I get the `UndefinedFunctionError` again.

I'm running my tests from the project's root directory.

Comment: Can you post the code here? Have you tried calling `mix do clean, compile` or just deleting the `_build` directory? What else have you tried so far?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing how phoenix endpoint is configured? is it in umbrella? what mix.exs file contents are? where _build folders are? especially in case of umbrella! what dependencies are added since some may fail silently? Did you add some code that depends on configuration? What version of phoenix and elixir u r using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test module was missing names as the `Test` suffix. In other words the module that was tested was called `MyApp.MyModule` and so did the module that was holding the tests.

If the module to be tested is named `MyApp.MyModule`, the tests should lie in 
`MyApp.MyModuleTest`

Comment: “the tests should lie in `MyApp.MyModuleTest`”—the wording is inaccurate. The name of the test might be arbitrary (I use `MyApp.MyModule.Test` for instance,) the only requirement it should not be the same as any of the existing modules.